# Adding footers to posts?

Tags: posts, footer

I'm trying to add footers to the end of my posts. I need to be able to assign different footers to different posts (not globally).

I tried using [WP Post Footer](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-post-footer/), but it's not working on WP 3.1.2.

Comment: Can you clarify this a bit? Do you mean you have say five different footers, and for a post you want to choose one of these (or no) footer, which should be added to the end of the post?

Comment: @Jan: That's exactly what I'm looking for.  I was able to get WP Post Footer working... see answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick solution for you:

on the page or post you want to add a post footer create a new custom field named `post_footer` and in the value add the footer content.

then paste this code in your theme's functions.php file

```
add_filter('the_content',`my_post_footer`,99);
function my_post_footer($content){
   global $post;
   $footer = get_post_meta($post->ID,'post_footer',true);
   if ($footer){
      return $content . $footer;
   }
   return $content
}
```

and you are done! 
This way you can have different footers on each page/post and none at all if you don't want it.

Answer (score 1):

Was able to get WP Post Footer working.  The online instructions at WP Plugin page is missing an instruction (found it in the readme in the zip pkg).

Need to add the following line to the Single.php module for the theme you are using:

```
<?php if (function_exists('wp_post_footer')) wp_post_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Anything you add, *inside the Loop*, but *after* the call to either `the_content()` or `the_excerpt()`, will, in essence, be a Post "footer".

Say you have:

```
<div <?php post_class(); ?>
     <div class="post-header">
          <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
     </div>
     <div class="post-entry">
          <?php the_content(); ?>
     </div>
</div>
```

You could do something like this:

```
<div <?php post_class(); ?>
     <div class="post-header">
          <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
     </div>
     <div class="post-entry">
          <?php the_content(); ?>
     </div>
     <div class="post-footer">
          <p>Hello! I'm a Post Footer!</p>
     </div>
</div>
```

To give specific instruction, we'll need to know what Theme you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Someone may have a more elegant solution, but if you're comfortable editing some of the template files, you can copy your footer.php and rename to footer-alt.php or whatever suits you. Make the changes you need, and in the template file you're using for the specific post-type, replace `<?php get_footer(); ?>` with `<?php include("footer-alt.php"); ?>`

If you keep the div and class names the same, you should not have any issues with the layout.

Cheers!

Comment: I think the OP is referring to footers for *posts*, rather than for the site as a whole?

Comment: You could call the custom footer file from within the specific post template, thus the "include" vs "get_footer" -- again, maybe not the best solution, but it's worked for me. :)

Comment: Rather than using `include( 'footer-alt.php' )`, use `get_template_part()` instead, e.g. `get_template_part( 'footer', 'alt' )`. **Note**: in order to avoid confusion, I would use a basename other than "footer", which has a specific meaning in the context of a WordPress Theme.